# What collection does excludeProperties parameter for TryUpdateModel refer to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model

Does `excludeProperties` parameter in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492957.aspx exclude properties from the model or the values from the Request?

E.g.

If I wish to exclude `Model.SomeProperty.SomeChildProperty` which has a name attribute of "Model.SomeProperty.SomeChildProperty", should I pass
`["SomeProperty"]`(name of the property on the model)
or
`["Model.SomeProperty.SomeChildProperty"]`(name of the field in the Request form)

To exclude it from the udpate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` will look at [`PropertyDescriptor.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.name.aspx) when filtering properties during model binding. You should use the model property name.

Comment: In this case `"SomeProperty"` since that's the name of the property on the model?